# VBA function returns wrong decimal values

Tags: vba, excel

Both of the function at the bottom return wrong values.

Example: for employee portion of `142.22`, the answer should be `165.64` , and not `165.39` as returned by the VBA function?

Similarly , for the second function, for `5048.94 - EmployerMPPportion` , the answer should be `50999.41`, whereas the answer is returning `51000`.

I am aware I have used round function but it should round up to 2 decimal points only?

I just read in the forum that *"BCD  are not very space-efficient, but that's a trade-off you have to make for accuracy in this case"*, if this is true then why do Excel's built-in functions always return correct values? Are they not designed in VBA?

```
Function MPPemployer (EmployeeMPPportion As Long)
    Dim c As Double
    c = Round((EmployeeMPPportion / (8.5 / 100) * (9.9 / 100)), 2)
    MPPemployer = c
End Function

Function Grossmppsalary (EmployerMPPportion As Long)
    Dim g As Double
    g = Round((EmployerMPPportion / (9.9 / 100)), 2)
    Grossmppsalary = g
End Function
```

Answer (score 2):

You should define what the Function returns and change the the Input type to Double for the parameters. The answer to why, is that the function had the input rounded to Long before the calculation.

```
Function MPPemployer(EmployeeMPPportion As Double) As Double
    Dim c As Double

    c = Round((EmployeeMPPportion / (8.5 / 100) * (9.9 / 100)), 2)

    MPPemployer = c
End Function

Function Grossmppsalary(EmployerMPPportion As Double) As Double
    Dim g As Double

    g = Round((EmployerMPPportion / (9.9 / 100)), 2)

    Grossmppsalary = g
End Function
```

Comment: @peter-Thanks for very quick reply.  , I just copy pasted your code to test i.e Unfortunately the code is still giving me the same wrong answer ?

Comment: @CAAmanGhotra If you are using these as UDFs (i.e. called from a cell in Excel), just updating the code is not sufficient to update the values in the cells - you need to force the cell to be recalculated so that it runs the new code.  Try editing the cells containing the formulas and just press enter (without making any changes) - that will recalculate it.

Comment: ...or press Ctrl+Shift+Alt+F9

Comment: @TimWilliams I can never remember which F9 key combination does what :D